# Stream.CopyTo() does not copy data under a certain length

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, stream, file-transfer

I am currently working on a Windows Store Application in which I have to take a picture, save it locally and then when a sync is called send it to a service which will save the picture on the server.

I am experiencing a problem in the copying of these pictures. What I do is the following :

1. Get a list of all the images in a specified folder and extract their `buffer.toarray` into a `bitearray`

   ```
   Dim fileList As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) = Await folder.GetFilesAsync()
   For Each file As StorageFile In fileList

       Dim Buffer As IBuffer = Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)
       fileBytes = Buffer.ToArray()
       lstfileBytes.Add(fileBytes)

   Next file
   ```
2. I then send it to my VB.Net service which saves the image to a file it created using `stream.copyto()`

   ```
   For i = 0 To lstMemoryPicturesReservoir.Count - 1
       Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("\\SERVER\Data\name.jpg", FileMode.Create)
       Dim memory As Stream = New MemoryStream(lstMemoryPicturesReservoir(i))
       memory.position = 0
       memory.CopyTo(fs)
   Next
   ```

This code is working for me except when the picture size gets small to a certain point. I noticed that when the `lenght` of my `ByteArray` is around **4000 or lower** the picture is not copying properly. When I open it in my *Windows Photo Viewer* I get the following error :

> Windows Photo Viewer can't display this picture because the file is
>   empty

Any idea of what could be causing this problem or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting both streams into `Using` blocks:

```
For i = 0 To lstMemoryPicturesReservoir.Count - 1
    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream("\\SERVER\Data\name.jpg", FileMode.Create)
        Using memory As Stream = New MemoryStream(lstMemoryPicturesReservoir(i))
            memory.position = 0
            memory.CopyTo(fs)
        End Using
    End Using
Next
```

`Using` blocks should be used wherever you:

1. Create an object of a class which implements the `IDisposable` interface, and
2. You start and finish using that object within the same scope

`Using` makes sure that the `Dispose` method of the `IDisposable` interface is called, even if an exception is thrown.

In this case, the `Dispose` method will ensure that all buffers are flushed before closing the streams. I suspect that the last 4000 bytes were not being flushed. In fact, I suspect you would have eventually noticed strange issues with images larger than 4000 bytes - some of them would have been missing the final buffer full of data. Not enough data to prevent them from displaying, but they would have appeared strange, to say the least.

Comment: Yes it works. I don't quite get what difference the `using` makes though

Comment: Nvm I have read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx which made it clearer

Comment: So, help an old guy out. "nvm" means what? "Nevermind"?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what it means

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new today.